# Can I mirror lo as eth0?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Is it possible to make eth0 point to lo? I have dumb process that keeps acting as eth0 exists while it doesn't.

Comment: I've tried making link on /sys/class/net but it didn't work...

Comment: It's possible instead to fix the dumb process?

Comment: does IPtables can help him @Braiam , I mean interface forwarding. I am not good with networking.

Comment: I don't know if you can do that directly but you may be able to bind eth0 to a TAP interface and then do forwarding from that.

Comment: @rajagenupula in this case no, because the interface doesn't exist at all.

Comment: ip link set dev lo name eth0
does the trick, but I lose lo.

Comment: Define "point to" and describe what this "dumb process" is doing.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a dummy interface called `eth0` — it wouldn't be exactly the same as `lo`, but should work:

```
# ip link add eth0 type dummy
# ip addr add 169.254.47.11/24 dev eth0 scope link
# ip link set dev eth0 up
```

**Edit:** Corrected the scope for (link-local address) `169.254.xx.yy`.